# Mozilla stop parent anchor tag behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code.

In Html parent element is `Anchor tag` and Child element is `Dropdown`.

I want to `stop parent behavious`.

Exa. When user click on dropdown so call dropdown change event and stop parent anchor tag behavious like `onclick or href value`

You can Edit in below url
https://jsfiddle.net/z4c4gwxa/

Comment: It's not valid HTML to have interactive content (like a `<select>`) inside an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop propagation on your dropdown's change event to prevent it from bubbling up the DOM tree, and check the `e.target` on your anchor tag's click event to ensure it was fired by itself.

[e.stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
$( function () {
    $( "a" ).click( function ( e ) {
        if ( ! $( e.target ).is( $( this ) ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        alert( 'parent' );
    } );
    $( '#dropdown' ).change( function ( e ) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert($(this).val());
    } )
} )
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
    <option value="3">Option3</option>
  </select>
  Click this part
</a>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4c4gwxa/2/)